# Is there a specific phrase for annoucing a schedule?

Tags: phrases

Is there a specific phrase (phrases) for **announcing a schedule?**

Comment: Now hear this?  What would be different for a schedule?

Comment: Are you announcing by email, face-to-face, over the phone, via a loudhailer?  I don't really understand what you mean. How about saying, "Here is the schedule" Please explain exactly what sort of answer you are looking for. A sample sentence would help.

Comment: I have to write a simple title (ex. Process Details , Profit Management)  for a manual.

Comment: @Grace - I'd like to help, really I would but I simply don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Schedule details?  (BTW, not my downvote.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to write a simple title (ex. Process Details , Profit Management) for a manual.
>
> Is there a specific phrase (phrases) for announcing a schedule?

Issuing, planning, publishing, creating, defining, providing, sharing, building

Or:

Chapter Four: Scheduling